# Using CSS nth-child on nested map in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I built a grid using a table and a 2D array like so:

```
        <table className = 'table'>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.board.map((x,i)=>{
                return(
                  <tr key = {i} className = {"row"}>
                    {x.map((y,j) => {
                      return (
                        <td key ={j} className = {"col"}>

                        </td>
                      )
                    })}
                  </tr>
                )
              })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Which prints a nice 8x8 grid onto the screen. I was trying to figure out a way to use the nth-child css selector to color all the odd squares one color, but I haven't been able to get anything to work thus far. I have tried `table tr td: nth-child(odd){background: blue;}` and that didn't work either. Is this something I can actually do with the way I created my grid?

Comment: Can you provide the whole example code? Like the entire component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you require a `checkerboard` pattern.

In that case you need **two** selectors

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd),
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 1em auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd),
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, if you actually want only the "odd" cells then one selector will work

```
table tr td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 1em auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

table tr td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span> 
  <span></span> 
  <span></span>
  <span></span> 
  <span></span> 
  <span></span>
</div>

span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
}
span:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #000;
}
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jzw0m61v/5/